# My Mongo queries running slow although indexed

Tags: mongodb

I am working on optimizing my Mongo requests but somehow my queries are slow although I have Indexes. I guess they have not been set up correctly.

I have a collections that has documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2a69879a8d4e03f69522c1"),
    "id" : "fbc1ccac69611504c06ca3018121b7231ce14a10",
    "sessions" : [ 
        {
            "webInstanceId" : 1,
            "timeStart" : 1495743152,
            "timeEnd" : 1495743152,
            "isPersonalized" : false,
            "context" : {
                "geolocation" : {},
                "weather" : {},
                "device" : "unknown"
            },
            "pageViews" : [ 
                {
                    "url" : "http://www.site1.fr/page1",
                    "id" : 658936,
                    "timeStart" : 1495743152,
                    "timeEnd" : 1495743152,
                    "events" : []
                },
                {
                    "url" : "http://www.site2.fr/page2",
                    "id" : 658936,
                    "timeStart" : 1495743152,
                    "timeEnd" : 1495743152,
                    "events" : []
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    "profile" : {
        "physical" : [],
        "tastes" : [],
        "otherCriteria" : []
    }
}
```

And I am trying to make an aggregation to get all other page URL that have been visited in sessions where the user also visited the "source_url". The final idea is to get a list of all URLs that might be interesting (and thefore not in the list of already visited pages) for the user that is looking at the URL "source_url"

The issue here is that my collection is 100GB big, and my queries take veryyyyy long although I got an index on 'sessions.pageViews.url'.

```
aggregate([
    {
            '$match': {'sessions.pageViews.url': source_url}
    },
    {
            '$project': {'sessions.pageViews.url': 1}
    },
    {
            '$unwind': '$sessions'
    },
    {
            '$match': {"sessions.pageViews.url": source_url}
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            'intersection': {
                '$size': {
                    '$setIntersection': [
                        "$sessions.pageViews.url", visited_pages
                    ]
                }
            },
            'difference': {
                '$setDifference': [
                        "$sessions.pageViews.url", visited_pages
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        '$match': {'difference.0': {'$exists': True}}
    },
    {
        '$sort': {'intersection': -1}
    },
    {
        '$limit': 100 * result_amount
    },
    {
        '$unwind': '$difference'
    },
    {
        '$match': {"difference": {'$ne': source_url, '$regex': filter_regex, '$nin': urls_to_exclude}}
    }
])
```

```
#### The index
{
    "sessions.pageViews.url" : 1
}
```

When cached, this query is lower than a second. But mostly, it takes 10-12 seconds.

I know this is not normal, even on a huge collection. Does someone have an Idea of what is wrong ? I am either guessing that the index is not optimal or that the sort is the killer.

Comment: Use explain to see what's actually happening with these queries -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/

Comment: Here is the output of the explain. I don't see anything wierd... https://pastebin.com/Sk5juTme

Comment: Yeah, nothing jumps out at me there. Could you include the executionStats? There might be a stage that's doing something odd -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain

Comment: Here is the explain with the exectionStats verbose. https://pastebin.com/SgVGUjUq

What does "indexFilterSet" : false," mean ?